# is there a patch shape editor in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

Is it possible to edit the shape of a patch in the same way a turtle can be edited?

To make my question more precise, in my model patches are different crops (yellow for cereals, green for fruit trees, etc). Some of the patches have hedgerows and other don't. I wonder whether it would be possible to make a patch with the crop color in the middle and a dark green frame on the edge of it in order to get this kind of shape that would help visualize them?

[image: Patch with hedgerow]

The solution I can imagine is to generate a turtle in a shape of a hedgerow but before doing that I wanted to check if there's another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can but you have to use the turtle shape editor.

1) make a rectangle from the top left corner to the bottom the thickness you want your hedge wall to be.

2) hit duplicate

3) rotate left

4) repeat 2 3 until it makes an empty rectangle looking like the one in your picture.

5) save it as hedgerow or whatnot

have the patches where you want hedgerows call

```
sprout 1 [set shape "hedgerow" set color green set heading 0]
```

using turtles for purely cosmetic purposes has been frowned on as it uses resources.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't edit a patch shape and they have a consistent colour for the whole of the patch. I would achieve that effect by having the opposite of what you are suggesting:

```
> patches with hedgerow are coloured green
> patches with hedgerow have a yellow square turtle in their centre
> patches without hedgerow are coloured yellow
```